# Apache stuck when MySQL executes a lot of commands

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am having an uncomfortable issue with my locally configured Apache + PHP5.6 + MySQL Windows 10 machine.

Everything runs smoothly, but I have noticed that when I execute a process that does a lot of queries and is time and resource consuming, Apache just waits for the process to finish and once it's done it is responsive again.

So, it's something like this:

1. I start the import PHP process.
2. Once it starts running, my browser tab shows that it's working.
3. Until the process times out (based on php's `max_execution_time` variable) I can't do anything else that concerns localhost.

My question is: is this a configuration issue related to Apache, PHP or MySQL and how can I fix it? (if it is fixable)

I am using the following:

- OS: Windows 10 1803 Edition
- Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Win64) Server built:   Dec 16 2016 23:05:57
- PHP 7.2.7 (cli) (built: Jun 19 2018 23:14:45) (ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64)
- MySQL Server: v5.7.23.0

Any help would be appreciated, I don't think I am the only one with this issue.

**EDIT (MORE INFO)**

- If I try in the same browser in another tab, Apache just waits for the process to finish and doesn't return anything in the meantime.
- If I open another browser, Apache sometimes works but other times (usually after a few minutes) it also stops returning anything and waits for the process to finish.
- Apache uses about 1.5% of the CPU and 100 MB of RAM.
- I have plenty of resources on the computer so it's not a resource exhaust issue.
- Also in PHP I have assigned 1 GB of memory available to use, so it shouldn't have issues with that.
- In my scripts I read remote files, could that be an issue?

Comment: Please clarify. Does apache refuse to serve other pages, even simple text pages, while this import operation runs? What does the Performance tab of the windows task manager say about CPU and Memory resource exhaustion? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Done @O.Jones it's not really a resource problem, I have plenty of resources on the machine, my theory is it could be something thread-related, but I am not really familiar with that topic so I am not sure. The weird part is that normally on a different browser it works, but sometimes it doesn't work even there. So I am not sure if it's something resource-limiting-apache-related thing.

Comment: which is it ? php 5.6 or 7.2 , when invoked via apache ? What are your mysql `Max_connections` and `Max_used_connections` and `Threads_connected` during the episodes ?

Comment: Perhaps you should check both mySQL and Apache configurations and verify that both are set up so they can run multiple parallel processes. This is not necessarily the default. I can't remember the exact directives in Apache, but you may Google them. You can configure the amount of threads and child processes on each thread that can be serviced at the same time before new requests start getting queued